# How to join list with different types of elements in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list1 = [1,"3",2323,"pause"]
list2 = ["2","4","5"]
print ",".join(list1)
print ",".join(list2)
```

For the above code, the elements of `list2` can be connected without any problems. But the join of `list1` reports error

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

I know that `join` works only for strings, then how to join the elements of a list with different types?

Comment: People have provided solutions, but I'd like to point out -- the problem isn't that the items in `list1` have different types, but that there are non-strings in `list`. Join only works on lists of strings.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Convert the items to strings first.

```
",".join(str(elem) for elem in list1)
```

or

```
",".join(map(str, list1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.join()` will work only on list of string. So, apply `str()` to each element! `map()` builtin function will come in handy.

Try yourself, if you're gonna have problems - come back ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
list1 = [1,"3",2323,"pause"]
list1 = [str(item) for item in list1]
print ",".join(list1)
```