# Making a list of randomly selected items

Tags: python, class

I need to make a list or tuple containing a series of 10 numbers and five letters. Then randomly select four numbers or letters from the list and print a message saying that any ticket matching these four numbers or letters wins a prize.

The code I tried, but it didn't know what to write ahead:

```
possibilities = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

winner = []

print("winning ticket is...")

while len(winner) > 4:
    pulled_item = choice(possibilities)

    if pulled_item not in winner:
        print(f"we pulled a {pulled_item}!")
        winner.append(pulled_item)
```

What should the code be which tells both of the number selected and winning number?

Comment: First you need to search what you can do about "random" selection in python.

Comment: This is so vague. What is working? What is not? Do you need help finding how to select a random item from a list?

Comment: This might work better if you made your test `while len(winner) < 4`. Your test as it stands is always `False`. So nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use the package random then

```
from random import randint

possibilities = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
winning_ticket = ""
print("Winning ticket is...")

for x in range(4):
    winning_ticket += str(possibilities[randint(0, len(possibilities)-1)])
    
print(f"Any ticket matching {winning_ticket} wins a prize!")
```

Comment: i want the four numbers selected also

Comment: What four numbers? And what do you mean by selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the choice function from Pythons inbuilt random library.

```
from random import choice

possibilities = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

# choose four items from the possibilities
chosen = [str(choice(possibilities)) for _ in range(4)]

# print the four chosen items
print(f"Any ticket matching {''.join(chosen)} wins a prize!")
```

This code makes an array of the four pulled numbers or letter, and then print the entire array at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way of doing it random.choices() and NOT .choice(). 
choices() has a built-in optional parameter that allows me to select the length of the returned list:

--- example:---

```
random.choices(possibilities, k=4) # will return 4 random selection in a list
```

Also, I wanted the final version not in a list format:
not this: [5, 'c', 'b', 1] 
but this: 5cb1

So, I used join with no delimiter, but i had to  convert the returned list to str first as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141793/how-to-join-list-with-different-types-of-elements-in-python/20141816#20141816).

here is the full code:

**Version 1:** return only 4 random characters \

**EDIT:**

- Adjusted some naming for better readability.
- Corrected typo in **int** to **init**
- Set default value for the selection parameter to None , since i am not supplying it at this point. I just need to initialize it but not calling it.

```
class LotteryTicket:
    """Randomly select characters and compose ticket number."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializing attributes."""
        self.selection = None

    def generate_ticket(self):
        """Randomly select a series of characters to generate tkt num."""
        series = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        self.selection = choices(series, k=4)
        return "".join(map(str, self.selection))


ticket_number = LotteryTicket()
print(f"\nWinning ticket number is: {ticket_number.generate_ticket()}\n")
```

Result:

```
Winning ticket number is: d881
```

---

If you want to take it a step further where you'll have the option to specify the length of characters for the tkt#:
Just add a parameter to the generate_tkt() method and use it for your k parameter in the returned list:

```
def generate_tkt(self, length):
    self.selection = choices(series, k=length)
```

**Version 2:**  return a random characters based on a length value when calling the method \

**EDIT:**

- Adjusted some naming for better readability.
- Corrected typo in **int** to **init**
- Set default value for the selection parameter to None , since i am not supplying it at this point. I just need to initialize it but not calling it.

```
from random import choices


class LotteryTicket:
    """Randomly select characters and compose tkt number."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializing attributes."""
        self.selection = None

    def generate_ticket(self, length):
        """Randomly select a series of characters to generate ticket number."""
        series = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        self.selection = choices(series, k=length)
        last_drawn = "".join(map(str, self.selection))
        return last_drawn


ticket_number = LotteryTicket()
print(f"\nWinning ticket number is: {ticket_number.generate_ticket(8)}\n")
```

Results:
8 characters tkt#:

```
Winning ticket number is: ae8e4836
```

5 characters tkt#:

```
print(f"\nWinning ticket number is: {tkt_num.generate_tkt(5)}\n")
```

```
Winning ticket number is: bd3ac
```

10 characters tkt#:

```
print(f"\nWinning ticket number is: {tkt_num.generate_tkt(10)}\n")
```

```
Winning ticket number is: 5b96a3e987
```

---

**EDIT:** Added version 3 and 4

**Version 3:** 
If you just wanted to do it using one function, it can be done like this:

```
def generate_tkt(length):
    """Randomly select a series of characters to generate tkt num."""
    series = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    selection = choices(series, k=length)
    last_drawn = "".join(map(str, selection))
    return last_drawn


print(f"\nWinning ticket number is: {generate_tkt(8)}\n")
```

---

**Version 4:**

This is another but simple way of generating a ticket number

```
from random import choices

series = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
selection = choices(series, k=4)
last_drawn = "".join(map(str, selection))

print(f"\nWinning ticket number is: {last_drawn}\n")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
from random import choice
lottery = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

win = [];

for value in range(4):
    choose = choice(lottery);
    win.append(choose);

print(f"Any ticket matching {win} wins a prize")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?